# Unable to find element on ServiceNow login page

Tags: javascript, selenium

Selenium is unable to find the elements concerning **UserName** and **Password** on ServiceNow login page (https://ven01718.service-now.com/navpage.do).

Whereas those 2 elements have distinct id, like UserName

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="user_name" name="user_name" value="" autocomplete="off">
```

So I tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.id('user_name')).sendKeys("user1");
```

And Selenium returns an error:

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[id="user_name"]"}
```

Comment: Have you tried waiting for the element to render? https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/

Comment: There is also an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

There was an iframe in the way.

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("iframe[id='gsft_main']")

driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```